# Displaying multiple ArcMap documents in one file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a project in which I'll have 22 different maps that I'll need to display on a single 3' x 4' poster. Each map is an individual .mxd file in ArcMap. How can I best accomplish putting these 22 maps in a single visual array?

Answer (score 5):

You can add the 22 data frames in one single map document (copy and paste) or you can export all as images/vector files and combine in Illustrator/Photoshop.

Comment: That's the way I'd do it, make it somebody else's problem! Just export all 22 as individual PDF files and get somebody else to paginate in Acrobat/Illustrator/Photoshop; I've seen someone do this and it's very easy and quicker than letting each frame redraw in ArcMap, individual maps can be updated quickly by replacement and PDF files can be resized a little without much problem - I would try to use scale bars instead of absolute scales as there's no way to accurately know how it would be printed. Then there's actually exporting all those maps on a page in ArcMap - just asking for problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.
Data driven pages is one,
if you know what you are doing - copying the data frame of each mxd into one mxd is another.
The most straight forward way is to produce high quality output of each mxd and put together the poster in your favorite software. i.e. photoshop, illustrator, paint, poster artist etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would try it this way:

1. Open a new Blank Map, switch to Layout View and set its desired page size.
2. Open each of your other 22 maps (which you will not alter) in turn.
3. Right-click on any data frames in the Table of Contents of each map that you want to appear on your large page and copy them to the clipboard.
4. Right-click on the layout of your large (originally blank) map and paste each data frame in.
5. Perform any necessary resizing of data frames as you go.